# SpeedDial: change color on click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-state

I'm trying to do so that if I click on a SpeedDialChild (button) then the color of it changes, but even if the value of fun.switchTakePhoto changes from true to false (and vice versa) the color remains red for some reason.

```dart
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Home createState() => Home();
}
 
@immutable
class Home extends State<MainPage> {
  //Home({super.key});
  var fun = FunctionManager();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChangePWD()),
            );
          },
          child: const Text('Change password'),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
          icon: Icons.settings,
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          children: [
            SpeedDialChild(
              child: const Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
              label: 'Activate/Deactivate: Take Photo',
              backgroundColor: fun.switchSendPhoto == true
                  ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 109, 255, 64)
                  : const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 64, 64),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  fun.switchTakePhoto = !fun.switchTakePhoto;
                });
              },
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
 
class FunctionManager {
  bool switchTakePhoto = true;
  bool switchSendPhoto = false;
  bool switchRec = true;
  bool switchPlay = true;
  bool switchNotifications = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you include full build method

Comment: @YeasinSheikh https://pastebin.com/NmLSfF57 here it is :)

Comment: How you are getting `fun.switchSendPhoto` , it is missing there

Comment: It is just before @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { as you wrote in the answer

Comment: @YeasinSheikh https://pastebin.com/Y4KQPJfG

Comment: it is missing `FunctionManager` now. Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry I missed it out while copying: class FunctionManager {
  bool switchTakePhoto = true;
  bool switchSendPhoto = false;
  bool switchRec = true;
  bool switchPlay = true;
  bool switchNotifications = true;
}

Comment: @YeasinSheikh mwe: https://pastebin.com/Q7kuPGJA

Comment: Are you trying to change yellow color button?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh for each speedchild (except help) I want to make sure that when pressed the color changes from red to green (so when that option is active => green, not active => red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be with data class. I've solve this way.

```dart
class FunctionManager {
  final bool switchSendPhoto;
  FunctionManager({
    this.switchSendPhoto = false,
  });

  FunctionManager copyWith({
    bool? switchTakePhoto,
  }) {
    return FunctionManager(
      switchSendPhoto: switchTakePhoto ?? switchSendPhoto,
    );
  }
}
```

A state-level variaable like

```dart
  FunctionManager fun = FunctionManager()
```

And update data

```dart
onTap: () {
   fun = fun.copyWith(switchTakePhoto: !fun.switchSendPhoto);
    setState(() {});
  },
```

Same goes for others